# Is there a way to get the id's of all members who are connected to a voice channel in a guild?

Tags: python, discord.py

Every way I found on the internet apparently doesn't work anymore with the latest Discord.py version.

If there is no way, is there a way to get all voice-channel id's? This would also fit what I want to achieve. I cant provide code since I deleted everything I've tried but I tried for two hours.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need a `VoiceChannel` [object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicechannel#discord.VoiceChannel).
Once you have this object, you can use the `members` attribute to get a list of members that are connected to the voice channel. You can then access the member objects one by one getting the ids.

Example:

```
member_ids = []
for member in voice_channel.members
    member_ids.append(member.id)
```

Comment: I have done that but my problem is, that I can't figure out a way to get all the channel id's. I only figured out how to get the channel names..

Comment: You can get a list of voice channels using `guild.voice_channels` then iterating over them to get their `.id` attribute

Comment: I know but every time I iterate the list, it just gives me the names instead of the Id's. Im sorry, if I'm being stupid.

Comment: If i run this, it just prints the names:

Comment: guild = client.get_guild(319545112629608449)
    vc_channels = guild.voice_channels
    [print(i) for i in vc_channels]

Comment: ╔ PhiJoTo-Privat
╠ Phantasialand-Lounge
╚ Freundes-Lounge
╔ Modprojekt-Lounge (Alle)      
╚ Modprojekt-Lounge (2 Personen)
╔ Among-Us-1
╚ Rocket League-1
╔ Andere Spiele-1
╚ Andere Spiele-2
Schlafplatz
AFK

Comment: Just edit your post instead of posting it in the comments.

Comment: Im sorry, im relatively new to all this and do python since yesterday.

Comment: No problem. Gotta start somewhere. You can edit your post and include the code that's giving you issues. You can encase your code using the ` symbol so that it's formatted.